# how to decode UTF-8 to HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby, encoding

I have an HTML document saved in my database as follow:

```html
\\u003cp style=\\\"text-align: center; opacity: 1;\\\"\\u003e\\u003cstrong\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\\\"font-size: 18pt;\\\
```

I know, it is ugly and I know, it is not the desired way but this is a legacy system.

My task is to get all these HTMLs and convert them to a document in Google Docs. Actually, Google Docs can parse HTML to their internal format pretty good but the HTML needs to be a valid HTML, with `<p>` instead of `\\u003cp`.

I'm trying to convert/decode/parse/whatever this string to a valid HTML but so far, without any luck.

#### Things I already tried

htmlentities gem, CGI decode, `Nokogiri::HTML.parse`, `JSON.parse` and none of them did the job.

I also tried `string.encode(xxxx)` but also without luck. I was really hoping that `.encode` method would do it but I couldn't make it work, maybe I'm using the wrong encoding? (I tried use all of `ISO-xxx` encodings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick workaround for you:

```
input_string.gsub(/\\u(\h{4})/) { [$1.to_i(16)].pack('U') }
```

With the example input you gave above, this results in:

```
"<p style=\\\"text-align: center; opacity: 1;\\\"><strong><span style=\\\"font-size: 18pt;\\"
```

---

Explanation:

`\u003c == <`. The left hand side is an escaped unicode character; this is not the same thing as `\\u003c`, which is a literal backslash followed by `u003c`.

The regular expression `\\u(\h{4})` will match any occurrences of this (`\h` stands for "hexadecimal" and is equivalent to `[0-9a-fA-F]`), and [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) converts the binary sequence into (in this case) a UTF-8 character.

---

Ideally of course, you'd solve the problem at its root rather than retro-fit a workaround like this. But if that's outside of your control, then a workaround will have to suffice.

Comment: I'd love to solve this in the root but it is totally outside my scope/time, unfortunately. also, thanks very much for the explanation on the whole hexadecimal conversion, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array#pack`:

```
string = "\\u003cp style=\\\"text-align: center; opacity: 1;\\\"\\u003e\\u003cstrong\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\\\"font-size: 18pt;\\"

string.gsub(/\\u(....)/) { [$1.hex].pack("U") }
# => "<p style=\\\"text-align: center; opacity: 1;\\\"><strong><span style=\\\"font-size: 18pt;\\"
```

Comment: the code **kinda** worked, the generated HTML was invalid somehow but it was a great start, thanks a lot!